# Schemas not showing in Google Now or Google Search

Tags: gmail, google-search, schema.org, google-schemas, google-now

I am using the [App Script Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/apps-script-tutorial) to send emails to my Gmail account. I have been sending emails with various schema to see whether they appear in other Google products. According to the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/google-search) and [this page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/google-now), schemas such as Flights and Events should appear in Google Now and Google Search results.

I have been using the examples cut-paste from the Google Schema documentation for the following types...

- Events
- Flights
- Restaurant Reservations

However I can't get any of them to appear in Google Now nor in Google Search.

The emails are appearing in Gmail. If I view the source of the email, I can confirm that the schema information exists in the HTML source. I am sending the email to my own gmail account (as per the App Script tutorial).

I have confirmed that the App Script example is configured correctly, as I can get actions to appear in Gmail if I embed an Action schema into the email. However, I was hoping to test the other schemas and cross-product integrations.

Could someone please enlighten me as to where I might be going wrong. Has anyone been able to get the cross-product schemas working? Are there any restrictions on using this cross-production functionality, such as restrictions on language or location? (I haven't been able to find anything to suggest this, but wouldn't be all that surprised if it were restricted to US/English or something?)

Comment: Hi how did you get solution for this? I'm having the same issue! Not getting google now cards after even getting email

Answer (score 1):

The markup in the page "Embedding Schemas in Emails" doesn't include any actions and Gmail doesn't currently render Events with specific cards, so that's why you don't see anything when receiving that email.

Try following the Apps Script tutorial we just published to get an easy way to send emails with schemas to yourself:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/apps-script-tutorial

Comment: How about showing up in Google Now or the Google Search Box? I have used the App Script to send emails to myself using the examples for Events, Flights, and Restaurants, but none are showing up in either of these products. I have adjusted the question to address this more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Key information provided via email markup should show up in Google Now, search, and now, Inbox. As mentioned earlier, Gmail only supports a subset (actions). Check out [the updated docs](http://developers.google.com/gmail/markup) for the Inbox launch.

More importantly, be sure that you've validated your markup using [these developer tools](http://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema) before sending to yourself. (BTW, in my own testing, I've discovered it's quite easy to "break" the markup with small syntactic errors.) If it doesn't validate, you'll get the email, but the markup enhancements won't show up.